# Black Litterman Model: can Market Weights be replaced?

Tags: black-litterman

I'm new to applying the Black Litterman model. One point that is troubling me, from a multi asset point of view, is the market portfolio as the starting point for the model. Correct me if I'm wrong but this is based on the entire estimated allocation of the market to a particular asset. So for a stock, this would be its market cap. A bond would be its entire issuance. However, when you apply it from a multi asset perspective it becomes more complicated.

For example, one approach I've seen applied is if using an etf tracking an equity index the weight within the market portfolio would be based the entire market cap of the equity index within the context of the entire investable universe of assets. Not just the AUM of the etf. Certainly more difficult to attain. But what about alternatives? Take an allocation to a long/short equity fund that invests in the same region as the etf. Surely you would be double counting here if you base the market portfolio's weight on the fund's aum? And this problem goes for many different alternatives or other strategies. What if you're allocation uses futures for example?

So, can the market portfolio be replaced in some way? My initial thoughts are that the aum of the specific instrument such as a fund or etf as the market portfolio's allocation is the correct approach. This is what the market has allocated to that specific instrument. But it can't be applied if you hold direct instruments as well. Perhaps there is a better way?